# <Router> is not working as expected in Blazor 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a working Blazor 7 WASM app . It has the following `<Router>` code in `App.razor` file :

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <h2>You are not authorized.</h2>
                <h3>To log in click <a href="/Accounts/LogIn">here</a>.</h3>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

I moved the same app in Blazor 8 Interactive Web Assembly and added the above code in the `Routes.razor` component in the Server project (that is, project without .client). But above code doesn't work anymore.

For example, all the app components that have [Authorize] attribute now throw 401 error instead of showing the `<NotAuthorized>` section above.

Similarly, navigating to a wrong URL doesn't display the `<NotFound>` section.

This works perfectly as expected in Blazor 7 but not working in Blazor 8. My Blazor 8 `Routes.razor` is given below :

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <h2>You are not authorized.</h2>
                <h3>To log in click <a href="/Accounts/LogIn">here</a>.</h3>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
       <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
       </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

I also tried wrapping the whole `<Router>` inside `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` but still problem persists.

What might be the problem? Where do I need to fix?

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the browser log? Are you getting any error there? In addition, please confirm, your authentication state is being properly cascaded through your components. The `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` component should wrap the entire content that relies on authentication. Make sure that the authentication state is correctly passed down to the components.

Comment: Browser show 401 error for all components that have [Authorize] attribute. No other error in browser console. I already tried putting the whole <Router> inside  <CascadingAuthenticationState> but no luck. This app works fine with Blazor 7. Haven't made any change to the JWT code and custom auth state. So, I think auth state must also be fine. What is the best way to check that auth state is correct ?

Comment: Well, in order to check if the authetication state working accordingly, you can inject the AuthenticationState service directly and check its properties to see if the user is 
`@inject AuthenticationState AuthenticationState
<p>IsAuthenticated: @AuthenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</p>`
It will allow you to inspect the authentication state at the component level and can help identify if there's an issue with how the authentication state is being handled. Make sure your middlware order is correct as well.

Comment: How many [Authorize] and where?

Comment: I checked the AuthenticationState in my code. Surprisingly, it is correct in all the components except in the MainLayout. So, authentication and authorization inside individual components works fine but the same code doesn't work in the MainLayout.razor.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have dealt with this problem today when I myself migrated to Net 8.

As the official docs say: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#provide-custom-content-when-content-isnt-found

> This section only applies to Blazor WebAssembly apps. Blazor Web Apps
> don't use the NotFound template

They advise is to use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#usestatuscodepageswithredirects

So what you need to do, is to add this line in your startup:

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode/{0}");

and then make pages with corresponding urls like this

@page "/StatusCode/404"   // For not found

@page "/StatusCode/x"   // For any other beside 401

and so on.

I hope it will help you, it works for me. (Although my project have blazor server background).

Comment: Can you explain this more. I am having trouble with getting NotAuthorized to work in the Routes file. When I go to a page I don't have access to I just get a white page with "403 Forbidden" not my custom message. Are you saying this does not work in Blazor 8 anymore?

Comment: In Blazor 8 <NotFound> section stopped working for me, so I had to use app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute() instead.  As for NotAuthorized section Blazor 8 made everything more confusing because now Web App is somewhat combined version of Server and WebAssembly.  When you use Server mode standard stuff is enough               <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="RouteData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
 <Authorizing> </Authorizing>  <NotAuthorized></NotAuthorized> </AuthorizeRouteView>    P 1/2

Comment: But for server stuff you also need to include (you did not have to in previous versions):

      services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddCookie(options =>
      { options.LoginPath = new PathString(UrlAdresses.LoginChallangeUrl); 
          options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(UrlAdresses.HttpCodes.NotAuthorized);
      });

And JWT for web assembly stuff. It really depends if you are using Auto, Server or WebAssembly. You need to specify it. P 2/2.

Comment: Can you add to your full answer, it's a bit hard to follow in your comment. I am using Blazor 8 Server with Per Component rendering and Windows Authentication.

Comment: @ArturChrzanowski: This fixed my issue in .NET 8 for my Status Code: 404. Thank you.

Comment: It's very important to highlight that you have to place the line app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode/{0}"); BEFORE the app.UseAntiforgery();, otherwise you will get an exception when the app tries to redirect to the 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Artur Chrzanowski's I was able to get it working. I found that there are some who are not clear on it, so I wanted to clarify on the process.
Please refer to Artur Chrzanowski's answer for more details.

Below are the steps I took:

1. Go to Program.cs and add the line "app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode/{0}");"

```cs
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode/{0}");
```

2. Navigate to Components\Pages and create a new Razor Component with a suitable name. (I used "NotFound.razor")
3. In this component, I wrote the below code.

```html
@page "/StatusCode/404"

<PageTitle>Not Found</PageTitle>

<h3>Not Found</h3>

<p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>


@code { }
```

4. Similarly you can create other razor components and write for the other pages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer following @Artur Chrzanowski's help.

.Net 8

Program.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using Blazr.RenderState.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Serilog;
using Syncfusion.Blazor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddUserSecrets<Program>()
.AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("X");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.AddBlazrRenderStateServerServices();

string baseAddress = string.Empty;

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment() == true)
{
    baseAddress = builder.Configuration["BaseAddress"];
}
else
{
    baseAddress = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BaseAddress");
}

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Initialize AutoMapper with the profile configuration
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
});

IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowBlazorApp",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(baseAddress)
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddSignalR(e =>
{
    e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
    e.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
});

builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI",
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress));

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("WebAPI"));

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// set Services
DIRegistration.SetServices(builder.Services);

//Add support to logging with SERILOG
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
{
    configuration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
        .Filter.ByExcluding(evt =>
        {
            var path = evt.Properties.ContainsKey("RequestPath") ? evt.Properties["RequestPath"].ToString().Replace("\"", string.Empty) : "";
            var method = evt.Properties.ContainsKey("RequestMethod") ? evt.Properties["RequestMethod"].ToString().Replace("\"", string.Empty) : "";
            var statusCode = evt.Properties.ContainsKey("StatusCode") ? int.Parse(evt.Properties["StatusCode"].ToString()) : 0;

            return (path == "/_blazor/disconnect" && method == "POST") ||
                   (path == "/_blazor/negotiate" && method == "POST") ||
                   (path == "/_blazor/initializers" && method == "GET") ||
                   (path == "/_framework/blazor.web.js" && method == "GET") ||
                   (path == "/_blazor" && method == "GET") ||
                   (path.Contains("/_framework")) ||
                   (path == "/" && method == "GET");
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<LogMiddleware>();

app.UseStaticFiles();

//Add support to logging request with SERILOG
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);

// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode/{0}");

// Inside Configure method
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.Run();

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/accessdenied");
```

NotFound.razor

```
@page "/StatusCode/404"
@using System.Diagnostics
<AntiforgeryToken />
<PageTitle>Not Found</PageTitle>

<h1 class="text-danger"><p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p></h1>

@code{
}
```

[image]

Comment: For anyone using this answer, it does work, you just have to make sure to put the app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode/{0}"); line BEFORE the app.UseAntiforgery();, otherwise you will get a runtime exception when the app tries to redirect to the error page.