# How to do Windows Authentication. I can't get NotAuthorized to show

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication, .net-8.0

I am using Blazor 8 (server and with per component/ per page) and trying to tie windows authentication into it, but I can't get "NotAuthorized" to work.

Routes.razor

```xml
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                Not Authroized
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Weather.razor

```cs
@page "/weather"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "test")]
<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
using BlazorApp11.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

namespace BlazorApp11
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });

            builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAntiforgery();

            app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
                .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? When I go to the Weather Page, I get 403 Forbidden with none of my layout. I was expecting to see "Not Authroized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  reproduced your issue and got a response :

[image]

I checked the NetWork tab in browser:

the .net 7 project:

[image]

.net 8 project:

[image]

It would send a request while it failed authorize,and the request would be blocked by the middleware

WorkAround:

Then I tried to customize the behavior of AuthorizationMiddleware,follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

```
    public class MyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();
    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next,HttpContext context,AuthorizationPolicy policy,PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {

        // Fall back to the default implementation.
        await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
        if (authorizeResult.Forbidden == true)
        {                
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
        

    }
}
```

.....

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, MyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
```

The content would be displayed now:

[image]

**Update**:

After some researching, I think the issue is mainly  related with  [render mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes),if you don't modify the default rendermode(Static Server) in app.razor,the parent component would work as a static page and always send a request ,and the request would be handled by middewares , when you haven't login/ not authorized, you would be redirected to target page  like MVC/Razor Page

So another workaround is apply IteractiveServer  render mode to the entire app:

```
<Routes  @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode()"/>
```

Now when I try with Identity Template,I could  see the custom content either:

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks, got a few questions. Why do you think this is happening,? I looked at when you create the "Individual Template in blazor 8" and it has in the NotAuthrozied with a Redirect.Login. If I remove that and put a custom message is always still redirects so I don't know this NotAuthorized is working out of the box.

Comment: I also tried this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/77511917/130015 which works for 404 as there is a problem with NotFound as well.  It idd not work with the 403 though.

Comment: Hi,@chobo2,I've updated my answer,hopes help

Comment: Ah yeah I thought rendering mode might be a problem, but I thought it may be on the individual pages (like the counter page) and tried to change it there. I am doing per component as that seems to be the direction MS wants us to go in. I am only using Server right now so I guess I could get away with just doing it global but gives me pause as it does not seem to be the direction MS is going.

Comment: Actually I just realized something that now it seems that all Roles lead to the forbidden page. Even if I have a role that is valid, I still get sent to the forbidden page. I thought I tested that but I guess not. So your code seems to always lead me to Forbidden page.

Comment: Do I need to add some logic to the HandleAsync? I looked at all the properties but I am not seeing anything that could be used to see it coming from a failed page.

Comment: Hi,@chobo2,I've updated  the handler,you may define a policy for Blazor ,and try policy based authorization follow the document

Comment: Hey I think this might have worked. I did try to create a policy but the Forbidden never changed. It seems I need that extra line you added in the middleweare. I am able to  use roles still and don't need create a policy. It seems to be working but I will keep testing

Comment: I also posted an issue in blazor here, you might want to post your soultion there as well so they can take it into consideration: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53100#issuecomment-1884770992

Comment: It's just a workaround not solution,and if you host MVC/api  together with Blazor ,the authorization won't work for them.So I considered add a policy that could check if you hit blazor endpointor mvc/api endpoints ,we could just wait for PG's answer

Comment: Yeah for now I don't have to wrry about MVC/api this is just a server project but still trying my hardest to keep with per component just to get use to that way or working so when we do go that way we understand better. Otherwise, I think I would just make it global and do your other way.  Who is PG?

Comment: I marked it as the solution for now and given you the bounty as the workaround does work till something more concrete comes along.