# How to inherit different MainLayouts to access pages where user is not authenticated?

Tags: .net, blazor, mudblazor, .net-8.0

This is from a project where everything is behind the login process. I am trying to make a page where anonymous user can also access some pages that do not require authentication, but it must retain the same styling and layout. I tried with checking `if(authenticated){ something } else { something else... }` but I was told that is not the best way to do, so I have to edit so that it inherits different layouts.

This is my `MainLayout.razor`

```html
.
.
.
<MudRTLProvider RightToLeft="@LayoutService.IsRTL">
    <MudDialogProvider/>
    <MudSnackbarProvider/>
    <MudThemeProvider @ref="@_mudThemeProvider" Theme="@LayoutService.CurrentTheme" IsDarkMode="@LayoutService.IsDarkMode" IsDarkModeChanged="@LayoutService.SetDarkMode"/>
    <MudLayout>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Small" Class="d-flex align-center" Style="height: 100vh;">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column mud-width-full">
                        <MudPaper Elevation="25" Class="pa-8" Width="100%" MaxWidth="500px">
                            <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor" Size="Size.Large" Style="width:100px; height:100px;"/>
                            @Body
                        </MudPaper>
                        <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Info" Class="mt-8 mud-width-full" Style="max-width:500px;">
                            @L["authentication is required, click"] <MudLink Href="/"> @L["sign in"]</MudLink>
                        </MudAlert>
                    </div>
                </MudContainer>
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorized>
                <HeaderMenu NavigationMenuDrawerOpen="_navigationMenuDrawerOpen"
                            OpenSearchDialog="OpenSearchDialog"
                            IsDarkMode="@LayoutService.IsDarkMode"
                            ToggleNavigationMenuDrawer="ToggleNavigationMenuDrawer"
                            RightToLeft="@LayoutService.IsRTL"
                            RightToLeftToggle="LayoutService.ToggleRightToLeft"
                            OnSettingClick="@(() => _themingDrawerOpen = true)"/>
                <NavigationMenu DrawerOpen="_navigationMenuDrawerOpen"
                                DrawerOpenChanged="NavigationMenuDrawerOpenChangedHandler"/>
                <ThemesMenu ThemingDrawerOpen="_themingDrawerOpen"
                            ThemingDrawerOpenChanged="ThemingDrawerOpenChangedHandler"
                            UserPreferences="_userPreferences"
                            UserPreferencesChanged="LayoutService.UpdateUserPreferences"/>
                <ThemesButton OnClick="@(() => _themingDrawerOpen = true)"/>
                <MudMainContent>
                    <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraLarge" Class="mb-4 mt-4">
                        <ErrorBoundary @ref="_errorBoundary">
                            <ChildContent>
                                @Body
                            </ChildContent>
                            <ErrorContent Context="exception">
                                <CustomError Exception="exception"></CustomError>
                            </ErrorContent>
                        </ErrorBoundary>
                    </MudContainer>
                </MudMainContent>
                <UserLoginState/>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </MudLayout>
</MudRTLProvider>
.
.
.
```

How can I change this piece of code, so that for respective pages uses respective layouts.
Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: What is the issue with your current solution?

Comment: AuthorizedView has two components inside, Authorized and NotAuthorized, basically if not authorized, it redirects to a sign in page but I want to be able to allow not authorized routes and inherit from the layout that is in the Authorized layout. Basically both authorized and not authorized must have the same look

Comment: You can put multiple `<AuthorizeView>` inside the main layout, that way you can share the common visuals (by not putting them in authorized view)...

Answer (score 0):

> basically if not authorized, it redirects to a sign in page but I want
> to be able to allow not authorized routes and inherit from the layout
> that is in the Authorized layout.

Since there's .net 8 tag  on your question,I think it is related with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748801/how-to-do-windows-authentication-i-cant-get-notauthorized-to-show/77750838#77750838),your request from static component was blocked by the authorization middleware and redirected to another page

make sure you've called :

```
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

If you would accept setting your entire app's render mode to InteractiveServer,

You could configure as below in app.razor:

```
<Routes  @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode()"/>
```

If you want to keep specificing the render mode per component,and don't have webapi,razor pages.... in the same host,you may try customer the authorization middleware:

```
public class MyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();
    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next,HttpContext context,AuthorizationPolicy policy,PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {

        // Fall back to the default implementation.
        await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
        if (authorizeResult.Forbidden == true)
        {                
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
        

    }
}
```

register it:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, MyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
```